# Archivo compilado muy grande

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Tengo una app bastante sencilla desarrollada en swift. Cuando genero el fichero para subir al itunesconnect me genera un archivo de 104MB. Otras app en ObjC subidas ocupaban unos 4 ó 5 MB.
Para generar el archivo primero hago un Product->Clean y después un Product->Archive, no tengo imagenes ni nada que puede hacer que ocupe tanto.
ItunnesConnect me deja subir pero me da un warning
¿Alguien sabe cual puede ser el motivo? ¿Debería ser así? ¿Alguna opción de compilación?

Comment: Utilizas algún framework externo? Podrías poner una captura del árbol de directorios expandidos para ver qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: No, no utilizo ningún framework externo, solo UIKit, UIMap y CoreLocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien, en `Swift 2.x` el `runtime` de `Swift` está embedido dentro de cada aplicación, y de ahí que ocupe tanto el binario. En más de una aplicación, al pasar a `Swift` o simplemente añadir código en el nuevo lenguaje, se ha pasado de ocupar apenas 10 Mb a 60 Mb ya que, como decía, el `runtime` se incluye dentro de cada binario. Con el tiempo debería desaparecer este problema ya que se integrará el `runtime` directamente en el SO y no hará falta incluirlo en el binario.

Pues encontrar más información [aquí](http://blog.diogot.com/blog/2014/09/29/swift-embedded-runtime-library-increases-app-size/) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275711/adding-swift-to-project-increase-size-substantiously-how-and-when-can-it-be-avo), por ejemplo.